# Asus K501U buzzing sound?

Tags: laptop, audio, asus-laptop

I purchased an Asus K501U laptop. Whenever I move the mouse, or built in touchpad an audible buzzing sound is made. It is impossible to hear with the fan on but when the computer is quiet it is quite an annoyance. Here's some specs, if it helps: Nividia GTX 950m Intel i7-6500U.

Comment: Sounds like a USB overcharge issue or possible grounding issue with the audio/USB ... Has it always happened (that you can remember) or has it just been recently? Does it happen when the mouse is unplugged (through the touchpad)? If you can, you could also open up the case and see if things at least "look" right ... ?

Comment: The laptop is about one week old but yes it has been making the buzzing sound since I got it. And, this is interesting, I think it might have something to do with the graphics because on my desktop the computer buzzes the second I mouse over something.

Comment: And yes it does happen with the mouse unplugged using the built-in touch-pad.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like manufacture defect, if is it that new, I suggest you return it and get a replacement for your money, because you don't know what other issues does it have. Other suggestion is to uninstall sound driver and download the latest version of sound driver from the manufacture website. Then install it and see how it goes. Even if the driver will fix the issue, you will experience this issue again as soon as you reset the laptop to the factory settings, and you will have to redo the process again. So, I highly suggest you return it and get a replacement or get better one.